Classify Cognitive Complexity value
I want to classify Cognitive Complexity into classes after quantifying Cognitive Complexity.
Similar to the way do with Cyclomatic Complexity in the image below.
For example, after we calculate and get a value of 20. How do we know if the 20 is good or not?
In the case of Cyclomatic Complexity, we use 1-10, 11-20, 21-50, and >50 to classify.
=> I want to classify Cognitive Complexity like that but I don't have enough knowledge and experience to define them on my own.

I came across an answer (in this post) of G. Ann from SonarSource Team, she recommended to use 15 as a threshold to evaluate but 15 may be hard for some projects.
My company would like to use a more flexible criteria for many project to comply with. For example, for some projects, 15 is ok, but for some projects, they don't have enough effort to keep it under 15, maybe 20 is acceptable.
Thank you very much for your help!!! I really appreciate it.
I tried to look for some criteria from many resources but couldn't find an answer.
